# loading webpages hosted on home server randomly fails

Tags: networking, dns, website, hosting, self-hosting

I have a server that is running from my home on a LAMP stack. I have a few sites that work fine when I am on my local network but when I try to access them from outside the local network they randomly do not load. Sometimes the page will load and sometimes it will give an error saying webpage not available because the server took too long to respond. Does this sound like purely a bandwidth issue?

Not sure if it matters, but the dns was setup with freedns.afraid.org and the connection from my home has a upload limit of 2mb and download limit of 15 mb on a dsl router.

Comment: Sounfs like a conflict with you using a home internet connection to host a server And likely a DNS propreigating probldm

Comment: the DNS name was setup a few months ago at freedns. Any recommendation on what to look into or how to debug the issue a bit more?